# Creating a ToolTip that shows all Validation.Errors for a control using INotifyDataErrorInfo in WPF 4.5

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, inotifydataerrorinfo

I have multiple controls including a TextBox and a ComboBox and I would like all of them to display a ToolTip with all of the errors contained in the Validation.Errors collection.  I would like them all to share a common style if possible, which is what I am trying.  I am convinced I am doing something wrong with my binding in the ToolTip setter, but I can't figure out what.  I return an Error object in my INotifyDataErrorInfo implementation that specifies the severity of an error (Error or Warning).

I would like to have a style that applies to all controls in the Window that would display a ToolTip containing a list of all errors and warnings for that control.  The errors should be displayed in red and the warnings in yellow.  Here is the Style I have come up with:

```
        <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent.ErrorMessage}">
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ErrorContent.ErrorSeverity}"
                                                             Value="{x:Static local:ErrorType.Warning}">
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent.ErrorMessage}">
                                        <TextBlock.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ErrorContent.ErrorSeverity}"
                                                             Value="{x:Static local:ErrorType.Warning}">
                                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </TextBlock.Style>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I have tried changing the RelativeSource to search for an AncestoryType of Control at both AncestorLevel 1 and 2.  None of this seems to work.

I based the style on a ControlTemplate that I used for the ErrorTemplate that does pretty much the same thing:  it displays a red or yellow border depending on the error severity and displays a ToolTip exactly like what I want to do for the ToolTip on the control itself.  I'm certain it has something to do with my binding, because the ErrorTemplate automatically has its DataContext set to the Validation.Errors collection, which makes it easy to bind the ItemsSource for the ItmesCollection.  The ToolTip for the style has no such luck.  Here is the working ControlTemplate I used for my ErrorTemplate:

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ErrorTemplate">
        <Border BorderThickness="1">
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="ElementPlaceholder"/>
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ElementPlaceholder, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent.ErrorSeverity}"
                                         Value="{x:Static local:ErrorType.Warning}">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
            <Border.ToolTip>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent.ErrorMessage}">
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ErrorContent.ErrorSeverity}"
                                                             Value="{x:Static local:ErrorType.Warning}">
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Border.ToolTip>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Can anyone give me any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After having tried to figure this out for quite some time, I finally stumbled on a [post on the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/32f08704-590b-4328-8f85-160dc2bb642d/validationerrors-notifypropertychanged-not-being-raised?forum=wpf) that led me down the right path.  First of all, I needed to specify Styles for each TargetType that I wanted and base them on the original.  Secondly, I realized that the problem was not in my binding, but in the fact that the collection that was bound to was not being updated.  I have no idea why my ListBox/ItemsControl was not being updated when specified in XAML, but it does work if you specify it in a converter.  Here is my new Style:

```
        <Style TargetType="Control" x:Key="ErrorToolTip">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent.ErrorMessage}"
                                       Background="Transparent">
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ErrorContent.ErrorSeverity}"
                                                         Value="{x:Static local:ErrorType.Warning}">
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors), Converter={StaticResource ErrorCollectionConverter}}">
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource ErrorToolTip}"/>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource ErrorToolTip}"/>
```

And here is my converter function:

```
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;
        return new ListBox
        {
            ItemsSource = (ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ValidationError>) value,
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(0),
            Background = Brushes.Transparent
        };
    }
```

I hope this is helpful to any others out there that are having my same problem.  If someone knows why this makes such a big difference, I would love to know.

Comment: Note that this code requires the use of a custom ErrorContent object with the properties ErrorMessage and ErrorSeverity defined on it. See 'Custom error objects' at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.wpf-4-5-validating-data-in-using-the-inotifydataerrorinfo-interface.aspx

Answer (score 9):

This could be achieved much easier.

If you write the binding to "Tooltip" as above:

```
<Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="ToolTip"
              Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},  Path=(Validation.Errors), Converter={StaticResource ErrorCollectionConverter}}">
      </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

The Binding "miraculously" actually rebinds itself to the "PlacementTarget" of the tooltip. Thus to the control it is attached.

If you need to display the full list of items you can do the below:

```
<Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="ToolTip">
          <Setter.Value>
               <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget}">
                   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)}" DisplayMemberPath="ErrorContent" />
               </ToolTip>
          </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

You could even drop the Tooltip object and bind to the PlacementTarget directly from the ItemsControl. Then just use the Tooltip as the RelativeSource via AncestorType on the ItemsControl.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

This is just a more simplified version of Matts answer that I used. It works only for controls of type `TextBox` and does not use an error severity.
I used for a case when I needed to display one or more errors in context of a directory path entered by the user. In contrast to Matts answer I used
     DisplayMemberPath = "ErrorContent"
to access the errors directly in the converter.

A style for a `TextBox` which shows the tooltip, when the attached property `Validation.HasError` is true:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ui:ErrorCollectionConverter x:Key="ErrorCollectionConverter"></ui:ErrorCollectionConverter>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},  Path=(Validation.Errors), Converter={StaticResource ErrorCollectionConverter}}">
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

My "Directory" `TextBox` implicitly using the style:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Directory, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"></TextBox>
```

The value converter directly accessing the `ErrorContent` property:

```
internal class ErrorCollectionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;
        return new ListBox
        {
            ItemsSource = (ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ValidationError>)value,
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(0),
            Background = Brushes.Transparent,
            DisplayMemberPath = "ErrorContent"
        };
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```